# ASP.NET MVC3 submit post passing a Dictionary to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dictionary being used. And when the "submit" is hit, how do I also pass the dictionary with the values in it to the [HttpPost] controller method? 
Currently in the [HttpPost] method, the DummyDictionary is empty, how would I fix this?

Thanks!

### MODEL

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using DummyMVC.Objects;

    namespace DummyMVC.Models
    {
        public class TheModel
        {
            public TheObject Obj { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, TheObject> DummyDictionary { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

### CONTROLLER

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using DummyMVC.Models;
    using DummyMVC.Objects;

    namespace DummyMVC.Controllers
    {
        public class DummyController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Dummy/
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                TheModel m = new TheModel();
                m.Obj = new Objects.TheObject();
                TheObject a_obj = new TheObject();
                a_obj.Name = "Joe";
                m.DummyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Objects.TheObject>();
                m.DummyDictionary.Add("VT", a_obj);
                return View(m);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(TheModel model)
            {
                // HERE THE DICTIONARY is EMPTY, where all the form values should exist.
                string test = "";
                return View(model);
            }

        }
    }
```

### VIEW

```
    @model DummyMVC.Models.TheModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DummyDictionary);
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DummyDictionary["VT"].Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DummyDictionary["VT"].Value)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DummyDictionary["VT"].Token, new { @Value = Model.DummyDictionary["VT"].Token, style = "display:none;" })
        <input type="submit" class="submit_button" /><br />
    }
```

In the view I am using @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DummyDictionary) to try to pass the dictionary over to the post method, but the dictionary is just empty. Without this @Html.HiddenFor the Dictionary in the post method is null.

Thank you so much for the assistance I appreciate it!

**UPDATE**

### TheObject

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace DummyMVC.Objects
    {
        public class TheObject
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Token { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might have to write a custom model binder.

Comment: Would you know of a good tutorial for that? Or a source? Thanks!

Comment: For writing custom model binders: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

Comment: Could you put your `DummyMVC.Objects` definition?

Comment: Did you read [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any way for the dictionary to exist in the model class, rather then having to pass the dictionary itself?

Comment: It will be same as in this article but there will be another prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty but it works. Remember to include all properties of TheObject, if not visible then hidden so they get posted. Would probably be a good idea to make a helper for this.

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TheModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DummyDictionary["VT"].Name)
    @Html.Hidden("DummyDictionary[VT].Name",Model.DummyDictionary["VT"].Name)
    @Html.Hidden("DummyDictionary[VT].Token", Model.DummyDictionary["VT"].Token)
    @Html.TextBox("DummyDictionary[VT].Value", Model.DummyDictionary["VT"].Value)


    <input type="submit" class="submit_button" /><br />
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TheModel m = new TheModel();
        m.Obj = new TheObject();
        TheObject a_obj = new TheObject();
        a_obj.Name = "Joe";
        m.DummyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TheObject>();
        m.DummyDictionary.Add("VT", a_obj);
        return View(m);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TheModel model)
    {
        // HERE THE DICTIONARY is EMPTY, where all the form values should exist.
        string test = "";

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but on the postmethod, DummyDictionary is still null when I use this code.

Comment: That's weird, I'll update answer with my test code because works great for me.